# issues with multithread and subprocess in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, subprocess

I am tying to run a loop with different treads to speed the process. And I don't find other way to do but to create another script and call it with subprocess and give it the big array as argument..
I put the code commented to explain the probleme..

the script I am trying to call with subprocess:

```
import multiprocessing
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import sys

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
inputs = sys.argv[1:]
print(inputs)


def evaluate_individual(ind):
    ind.evaluate()
    ind.already_evaluate = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # i am trying to execute a loop with multi thread.
    # but it need to be in the "__main__" but I can in my main script, so I create an external script...
    Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(evaluate_individual)(i) for i in inputs)
```

the script who call the other script:

```
import subprocess, sys
from clean import IndividualExamples

# the big array
inputs = []
for i in range(200):
    ind = IndividualExamples.simple_individual((None, None), None)
    inputs.append(ind)

# and now I need to call this code from another script...
# but as arguments I pass a big array and I don't now if there are a better method
# AND... this don't work to call the subprocess and return no error so I don't now who to do..
subprocess.Popen(['py','C:/Users/alexa/OneDrive/Documents/Programmes/Neronal Network/multi_thread.py', str(inputs)])
```

thanks for your help, if you now another way to run a loop with multi thread in a function (not in the main) tell me as well.
And sorry for my approximative english.

edit: I tried with a pool but same probleme I need to put It in the "**main**", so I can put it in a function in my script (as i need to use it)

modified code with pool:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tps1 = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(12) as p:
        outputs = p.map(evaluate_individual, inputs)

    tps2 = time.time()
    print(tps2 - tps1)

    New_array = outputs
```

Other little question, I try with a simple loop and with the Pool multiprocess and a compare the time of the 2 process:

```
simple loop: 0.022951126098632812
multi thread: 0.9151067733764648
```

and I go this... why the multi Process On 12 cores can be longer than a simple loop ?

Comment: Have you tried using a [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)?

Comment: no, It is my first test with multi process

Comment: yes it's work but it's also need to but in the "__main__" but I can put it there in my global script. So i call it with subprocess but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

```python
import subprocess, sys
from multiprocessing import Pool
from clean import IndividualExamples

def evaluate_individual(ind):
    ind.evaluate()

# the big array
pool = Pool()
for i in range(200):
    ind = IndividualExamples.simple_individual((None, None), None)
    pool.apply_async(func=evaluate_individual, args=(ind,))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I just try but this raise a run time error:

```
raise RuntimeError('''
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```